# Integration failed with react and Socketio

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am a newbie with react. And I want to setup a group chat with react and socket.io. But there has some difficulties when I try to do that. Below is my code sample. Any help will be appreciated.

Server.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

// Listen for a connection
// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function (room) {


        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = 'room1';

        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        console.log("join room1   " + room)
    });

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        console.log("message  " + JSON.stringify(data))
        // console.log(socket);
        socket.broadcast.in('room1').emit('updatechat', data);
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
})
```

Client.js

```
let name = "test"
socket.emit('adduser', name);
socket.emit("sendchat", message_text)

    socket.on('updatechat', function (data) {
        messages.push(data);
        console.log("Hello!!!");
    });
```

What I want to do is add the text message to the chat board. I have tried the broadcast like in the code and add it as state in the react component. However, it can only add the message with that certain user, What's wrong with my code?

Comment: In your client code you have `socket.emit("sendchat", message_text) ` without a `;`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is your using `socket.broadcast.in` Which emits to everyone but the user socket emitting the broadcast, Which in turn means only one of the clients will receive a message at a time.

Old function

```
   // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        console.log("message  " + JSON.stringify(data))
        // console.log(socket);
        socket.broadcast.in('room1').emit('updatechat', data);
    });
```

New Function

```
 socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        console.log("message  " + JSON.stringify(data))
        // console.log(socket);
        io.in('room1').emit('updatechat', data);
    });
```

As in the example we are trying to get everyone within the specific `room` to see the message we can use `io.in('room').emit();` to achieve what we are after.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. But I changed to io.in is still not working. However, if I only broadcast without in or to, it can broadcast success. I don't know why this happens?

Comment: That is very strange, http://socket.io/docs/# this says nothing about just broadcasting alone.. Maybe there's something in the example you haven't disclosed?